# Named stages as git checkout-index parameters

Tags: git

```
git checkout-index --help
```

says

> --stage=|all 
>   Instead of checking out unmerged entries, copy out the files from named stage.  must be between 1 and 3. Note: --stage=all automatically implies --temp.

I would like to understand what are the "named stages" corresponding to numbers from 1 to 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`git merge` manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) eplains:

> For conflicting paths, the index file records up to three versions: stage 1 stores the version from the common ancestor, stage 2 from `HEAD`, and stage 3 from `MERGE_HEAD` (you can inspect the stages with [`git ls-files -u`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files)). The working tree files contain the result of the "merge" program; i.e. 3-way merge results with familiar conflict markers `<<< === >>>`.